# Rendering A List in React

Tags: javascript, list, reactjs, firebase

I am creating a blog using React and Firebase. I have a component called Blogger that creates blog posts and then saves them in firebase. Now, I am trying to render a list of all of the blog posts that have been saved into firebase. I can't seem to get a list to render.

So far, I have created a parent component called Blogger and a child component called List. I want List to render a list of blog post titles within the Blogger component. I've passed the prop title to List like this

What am I doing wrong?

My stack is webpack + React + React Router + Flux + Firebase

I get this error:

[The error message I recieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VyoW.png)

This is my parent object in which the list is created:

```
import AltContainer from 'alt-container';
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import List from './List.jsx'
import Firebase from 'firebase'

const rootURL = 'https://incandescent-fire-6143.firebaseio.com/';


export default class Blogger extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.firebaseRef = new Firebase(rootURL + 'items/');




    this.state = {
      title: '',
      text: ''
  };

    this.firebaseRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
  });

  }



  handleInputChange = () => {

    this.setState({
      title: this.refs.title.value,
      text: this.refs.text.value});
  }


  handleClick = () => {

    this.firebaseRef.push({
      title: this.state.title,
      text: this.state.text,
      done: false
    })



    this.setState({title: '',
                   text: ''
                  });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row panel panel-default">
          <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <h2>
                Create a New Blog Post
            </h2>
          </div>
        </div>

<h2>Blog Title</h2>
        <div className="input-group">
          <input
          ref="title"
          value={this.state.title}
          onChange = {this.handleInputChange}
          type="text"
          className="form-control"/>
          <span className="input-group-btn">

          </span>
        </div>

<h2>Blog Entry</h2>
        <div className="input-group">
          <textarea
          ref="text"
          value={this.state.text}
          onChange = {this.handleInputChange}
          type="text"
          className="form-control"/>

        </div>

        <div className="blog-submit input-group-btn">
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}
          className="btn btn-default" type="button">
            Publish Blog Post
          </button>
        </div>

        <List title={this.state.title} />



    </div>


    );
  }

}
```

This is the child object to which I want to pass the props:

```
import AltContainer from 'alt-container';
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import Blogger from './Blogger'

export default class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log(Object.keys(this.props.title));
  }


  render: () => {

    return (

      if(this.props.title && Object.keys(this.props.title).length === 0) {
        return <h4>enter a blog entry to get started</h4>
      } else {
        var children = [];
        for(var key in this.props.title) {
          children.push(
            <li>
              {title.text}
            </li>
          )
        }
      }

    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Dude, the syntax is wrong. return (if (...) {} ) is unaccepted. Instead, you can do it like this: render() { if (x) return y else { [here you build your array] and return <div>{array}</div>}
Remember you shouldn't return an array but an element containing the array or else React will throw an error. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The error in your screenshot is quite clear. It's a syntax error.

The following is not legal JavaScript:

```
function foo () {
  return ( if (true) return 'hello )
}
```

Nesting return statements like this will crash.

The pattern you are looking for is more like this:

```
function foo () {
  if (cond) {
    return <List />
  }

  return <SomethingElse />
}
```

Additionally the way you are writing `render` is incorrect. Class functions should just be:

```
render() {
  // return stuff
}
```

Finally your `render` method should something like this:

```
render() {
  if (this.props.title && Object.keys(this.props.title).length === 0) {
    return <h4>enter a blog entry to get started</h4>
  }

  return Object.keys(this.props.title).map(key =>
    <li>{this.props.title[key]}</li>
  )
}
```

Comment: What's the error? I mean.. you had a pretty serious syntax error in the code.. there may be more of them. Perhaps it would be wise to do some JavaScript tutorials or read something like Eloquent JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

Blogger.jsx

```
import AltContainer from 'alt-container';
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import List from './List.jsx'
import Firebase from 'firebase'

const rootURL = 'https://incandescent-fire-6143.firebaseio.com/';


export default class Blogger extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.firebaseRef = new Firebase(rootURL + 'items/');




    this.state = {
      title: '',
      text: ''
  };

    this.firebaseRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
  });

  }



  handleInputChange = () => {

    this.setState({
      title: this.refs.title.value,
      text: this.refs.text.value});
  }


  handleClick = () => {

    this.firebaseRef.push({
      title: this.state.title,
      text: this.state.text,
      done: false
    })



    this.setState({title: '',
                   text: ''
                  });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row panel panel-default">
          <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <h2>
                Create a New Blog Post
            </h2>
          </div>
        </div>

<h2>Blog Title</h2>
        <div className="input-group">
          <input
          ref="title"
          value={this.state.title}
          onChange = {this.handleInputChange}
          type="text"
          className="form-control"/>
          <span className="input-group-btn">

          </span>
        </div>

<h2>Blog Entry</h2>
        <div className="input-group">
          <textarea
          ref="text"
          value={this.state.text}
          onChange = {this.handleInputChange}
          type="text"
          className="form-control"/>

        </div>

        <div className="blog-submit input-group-btn">
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}
          className="btn btn-default" type="button">
            Publish Blog Post
          </button>
        </div>

        <List title={this.state.title} />




    </div>


    );
  }

}
```

List.jsx

```
import AltContainer from 'alt-container';
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import Blogger from './Blogger'

export default class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // console.log(this.props.blog);
  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.props.blog)
  //   Object.keys(this.props.title[key]).map(key) =>
  //   <li>{this.props.title}</li>
  // )
    return (
      <div>
        <li>{this.props.blog.title}</li>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```