# Rendering a list into ListItems and Links

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
class Glass extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
         names: [{n: "Gemma", num: "01"}, {n: "Katie", num: "02"}],
       }
      }

     render() {
        const { list } = this.state;
        return (
          <div>
            <List component="hello">
              {list.map(name => {
                return (
                  <ListItem key={name.num}>
                    <Link to="/glassmates/" + name.num > //I keep getting error here saying unexpected token.
                      {name.n}
                    </Link>
                  </ListItem>
                  <Divider /> // also getting errror here saying adjacent jsx elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag
                )
              })}
            </List>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

I listed some errors I'm getting in the code, but I'm confused in general whether this is how you render a list into Links inside a ListItem and a List component...

Comment: There are a couple of problems, first, there is no `list` array in your state (I think you're looking for the `names` array), second, in the `map` function you'll need to return a single element, you're returning two (a `ListItem` and a `Devider`).

Comment: @Titus Hi Titus! I think I can fix it by putting both in a div!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering A List in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949157/rendering-a-list-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

```
{list.map(name => {
                return (
<div>
                  <ListItem key={name.num}>
                    <Link to="/glassmates/" + name.num > //Because your state not contains list==>names
                      {name.n}
                    </Link>
                  </ListItem>
                  <Divider /> // JSX should have on parent
</div>
                )
              })}
```

Comment: list.map(name =>

Answer (score 0):

Concerning you errors: for the first error, you should be using string interpolation, i.e:

```
<Link to=`/glassmates/${name.num}` >
```

Secondly, as stated `adjacent jsx elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag`.
Which means you could/should wrap your elements in a div:

```
<div> // parent
  ...
  <Divider />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, the string interpolation still doesn't work for some reason.